# Using LLVM headers when compiling LLVM IR

Tags: c++, llvm-ir

I am trying to compile C code fragment into LLVM IR.
I need to #include the appropriate LLVM header files, e.g Module.h 
(#include "llvm/Module.h").
For compilation I use:

c++ -g prog.cpp `llvm-config-10 --cxxflags --ldflags --libs core` -o prog

But that gives me an error:

c++ -g prog.cpp `llvm-config-10 --cxxflags --ldflags --libs core` -o prog
prog.cpp:1:10: fatal error: Module.h: No such file or directory

The output of llvm-config-10 --cxxflags is

-I/usr/lib/llvm-10/include ... etc

I have Module.h header in two locations:

/usr/include/llvm-10/llvm/IR/Module.h

and

/usr/lib/llvm-10/include/llvm/IR/Module.h

So, why does not "-I/usr/lib/llvm-10/include" work?

Shouldn't it find the header Module.h in .../llvm/IR directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `#include "llvm/Module.h` put `#include "llvm/IR/Module.h`.
Also, if you want to compile C code into LLVM IR, you can use the command `clang -S -emit-llvm source.c`, which will create a source.ll file containing the LLVM IR.